# How do I install FreeBSD without bsdinstall?

Tags: command-line, freebsd, system-installation

I would very much like to install and generally configure FreeBSD from the command line without using bsdinstall UI. How do I prevent the live CD from starting into bsdinstall and more important is there something similar like the Arch Beginners Installation Guide for FreeBSD? In the official docs I only found information about the install with bsdinstall.

Comment: Can you use pc-sysinstall?

Comment: `bsdinstall` may be used for unattended installation of FreeBSD. See [the `bsdinstall(8)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdinstall&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports).

Comment: Look at the `boot_command` of this file ... https://github.com/jlduran/packer-FreeBSD/blob/main/packer.pkr.hcl for hints.